# Windows 2012 VisualSVN cannot be connected to by Linux Subversion Client

Tags: linux, svn, windows-server-2012, visualsvn-server

I am trying to connect Subversion client on a Red Hat machine to a Windows Server 2012 machine with VisualSVN Server running. My goal is to run an `svn export` via a shell script on the linux machine to retrieve code for the development server.

First I tried to connect using the default https Repo connection string..

```
svn export --username user --password pass https://OPSSVN1/svn/volunteers/ ./svn-export
```

the linux box returns...

```
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (501 Not Implemented) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://OPSSVN1/volunteers'
```

So I went and installed svnserve.exe as a service listening on to 3960 and changed the script to..

```
svn export --username user --password pass svn://OPSSVN1:3960/volunteers/ ./svn-export
```

I get the following message

```
svn: Can't connect to host 'OPSSVN1': Connection refused
```

Now if I use either connection string from a window's desktop it works fine.

Other facts known that might help...

- The Windows server has the firewall opened up for the port.
- The linux box can ping the machine
- the linux box can Telnet into port 443 on the windows box
- The linux box cannot telnet into port 3960 on the windows box
- Linux SVN version: svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
- VisualSVN Version 2.7.2

The SVN service I setup on windows was done with the following command.

```
cmd /c sc create subversion binpath="c:\svnserve\svnserve.exe --service -r E:\Repositories --listen-port 3960"
```

With the folder svnserve being a symbolic link to the visualsvn bin folder thats in the program files x86 directory.

Any ideas on how I can get this linux box to export the code from VisualSVN?

Comment: Found this is probably going to be a linux issue. THe server I tried this from didn't like it. Another server that is similar it worked fine. They have the same version installed. I welcome any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like that you enter invalid URL.

   Where did you get the URL `https://OPSSVN1/volunteers/`? URLs of VisualSVN Server repositories usually look like `https://<hostname>/svn/<repository-name>`. In your case the URL has to be `https://OPSSVN1/svn/volunteers/` unless you hide VisualSVN Server behind a reverse-proxy.
2. You are using too outdated Subversion 1.6.11 client on Linux machine.

   Subversion 1.6 is no longer supported starting with 1.8 release. The particular 1.6.11 version was released on 19 Apr 2010 and is too outdated. It's behind 11 patch releases, in fact. The latest Subversion 1.6.23 client was released on 30 May 2013 and includes a lot of fixes. If you must use svn 1.6 client, at least update it to the latest patch release then.

   On the other hand, you have to consider upgrading your clients to [the latest Subversion 1.8 release](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html).

Comment: 1. The https://OPSSVN1/volunteers/ url was because that is was was needed to make the svnserve service that is listening to port 3960 find the files. The Typical url visual svn provides didn't work when using svn://, you are right in that the /svn/ is what the first attemp t actually had in it, I copied the second attempt and modified it for the post, So I will edit it.

Comment: 2. What is odd is on one linux server both with the exact same svn installed it gives me a connection refused and the other works.

Comment: @isisgate, VisualSVN Server does not support using `svnserve`. Don't mix the troubleshooting, because you have to investigate the original issue when using HTTP(S). `svnserve` is another story and using it won't help to troubleshoot this behavior I'd say.

Comment: Do you think updating the svn on the linux box will make the https version work ok?

Comment: @Isisgate it **may**, but I can't say for sure. Try the latest svn 1.6.23, 1.7.16 and 1.8.8: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Comment: I will do a "yum update svn" on the problem server and see what happens.

Comment: yeah looks like the filesystem is a little hosed. Everything is in read only mode which I can only venture a guess that it is due to e2fsck needs to be run. So I can't get an RPM on the machine via sftp or wget to try this. Will have to wait until monday when an person is in with vmware access to get a snapshot of the machine before hand.